# Converting String format to Date with ParseExact

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a strange problem in vb.net.

In this way, I have no problem converting a String to Date using ParseExact, some date format and CultureInfo:

```
   Dim f As String = "30-mar-2012"

   ' Value of f is "30/03/2012"

   xdate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                       f,
                       "dd-MMM-yyyy",
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Problem begins when using a DataReader

```
While dr.Read
     Dim f As String = String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", dr.Item("fec_estado_insc")))

    ' Value of f is "30-mar-2012"

     xdate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                       f,
                       "dd-MMM-yyyy",
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

End While
```

Get error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime "

As you see, variable **f** is a string, its value comes from a row of a datareader, but is stil a string.

How is possible this?

**EDIT**

I found a hack way to get date in "dd-MMM-yyyy" format with Chan's help. I had to create this function:

```
Public Shared Function Giveme_Date_dd_MMM_yyyy(ByVal XobjValue As Object) As Nullable(Of Date)

        If XobjValue Is System.DBNull.Value Then
            Return Nothing
        ElseIf XobjValue Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        ElseIf XobjValue.ToString.Trim.Equals("") Then
            Return Nothing
        End If

        Dim f As String = String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyy}", XobjValue)

        Dim dtResult As Date, xdate As Date

        If DateTime.TryParse(f, dtResult) Then
            xdate = CDate(dtResult.ToString("f", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

        End If

        Return xdate

    End Function
```

And in database, had to change SELECT query in this way:

```
OPEN r_cursor FOR
         SELECT to_char(fec_estado_insc,'dd/mm/yyyy') AS fec_estado_insc,
         blah
         blah
         blah
```

However, original problem persists. Some vb.net bug?

Comment: Maybe try this? `Dim f As String = CStr(String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyy}", dr.Item("fec_estado_insc")).Clone())`

Comment: Get same error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime ". It' strange. If I set directly variable f = "30-mar-2012", there is no error. But error appears when filling f value from DataReader.

Comment: Once you have set the value of `f`, it's a string. A string is a string irrespective of how it was set or sourced; it won't affect your next line. You are doing something wrong... just try stepping thru the code line by line and inspecting the variable values.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure the data is datetime?  What if it's null?  How about an additional check?

```
Dim f As String = "30-mar-2012"
Dim dtResult As Date, xdate As Date

If DateTime.TryParse(f, dtResult) Then
    xdate = dtResult.ToString("f", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

End If
```

Comment: I'm debugging and am abosolute sure that String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", dr.Item("fec_estado_insc"))) gets: "30-mar-2012". Problem is when that value enters into function DateTime.ParseExact.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the whole problem by storing the `Date` as a `Date`, then reading it back as a `Date`.  `Dates` dont have a format, they are just a value, but you can display them any way you want using format.

`ID  Name   RealDate    StringDate`
`1   Test1  3/30/2012   30-mar-2012`

The date can be read back as a Date this way:

```
' "SELECT Name, RealDate, StringDate FROM...
Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    rdr.Read()
    realDate = rdr.GetDateTime(1)

    Console.WriteLine("realdate type: {0}  value: {1} ", realDate.GetType, realDate)
    Console.WriteLine(realDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

Unfortunately, the type reader methods only work off an ordinal index, but returns the value as a Date.  The output:

> realdate type: System.DateTime  value: 3/30/2012 12:00:00 AM
>   30-Mar-2012

If the DB col is a Date type, the DB is only going to accept a Date type into the column.  To read it by column name you can parse or just convert:

```
realDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr("realdate").ToString)
```

When you "must" convert from string (assumes the "date" is "dd-MMM-yyyy"):

```
stringDate = rdr("stringDate").ToString
Console.WriteLine("String Date date: {0}", stringDate)
Dim newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Console.WriteLine("String Date reparsed: {0}", newDate)
```

Output:

> String Date date: 30-mar-2012
>   String Date reparsed: 3/30/2012 12:00:00 AM

If the data is in the database in some known data format, convert/parse it to date *then* try to apply a format.  On one piece of code, you are using `String` to do `DateTime` formatting and acting on `Object` (`dr.Item` returns object). There is no `Date` type involved.